# How to find x y and z of a game object in unity from anther game object

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I have my camera object and I have another object called untitled and it has a tag of player. I'm trying to find the position of untitled from the camera's script how would I do that. I tried myself but failed miserably.

Comment: If you need a reference to an object in your scene I usually create a public variable in the script then in the Unity editor a new field will appear in the inspector window. Drag the object directly into the new field to have it available in your script.

Answer (score 1):

Without testing, but this should do it.

```
public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private GameObject player;
    private Vector3 pos;
    player = GameObject.FindWithTag("player");
    pos = player.transform.position;  // This is the object position vector
}
```

And then word of warning. Don't add `GameObject.FindWithTag` - or any other methods which search something - to your update method. It is rather resource consuming. Find the game object somewhere else, for example use public variable and attach it in editor to your camera, or find it on constructor and save it to a variable.

Comment: I just have a small question, is Vector3D the same as Vector3.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. It should be Vector3, not Vector3D. I edited my answer.